# How can i run Chrome Canary with web security disabled flag?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-canary

Despite this [post](https://www.bryntum.com/blog/testing-x-domain-websites-with-siesta-in-chrome/) I have to run Chrome Canary with the web-security disabled modifier. I've ran this command;

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app --args --disable-web-security --/ChromeDisabled
```

It opens a flagged browser but some how the browser behaves as if it is not flagged and keeps giving this error below:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1841' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

And here is the screenshot that flagged notice;

[image: screen]

I'm pretty new to Mac therefore I couldn't run it in terminal. What is the problem with browser?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify both the `--disable-web-security` and the `--user-data-dir` as is documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/94928) and in the comments of [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=575690).

Comment: dear @heavyd what i got from this answers, i closed all Chrome browser and ran the command again but still it behaves as same.